# Can't start MySQL after ESXi reboot

Tags: linux, mysql

My MySQL server just stopped working after ESXi server restart...
It does not start automatically, and I can't start it from my Unix shell.

```
~# service mysql restart
restart: Unknown instance:

~# sudo service mysql start
start: Job failed to start

~# sudo -u mysql mysqld
~# 
~# netstat -tap | grep mysql
~#
~# service mysql restart
restart: Unknown instance:
```

Files at /var/log/ : mysql.err and mysql.log are empty.
File here /var/log/mysql/error.log has some info:

```
Version: '5.1.62-0ubuntu0.11.10.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
130410  9:50:54 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './radius/radcheck' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130410  9:50:54 [Warning] Checking table:   './radius/radcheck'
130410  9:50:54 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './radius/radpostauth' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130410  9:50:54 [Warning] Checking table:   './radius/radpostauth'
130410  9:50:54 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './radius/resv' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130410  9:50:54 [Warning] Checking table:   './radius/resv'
130819 22:31:21 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130819 22:31:21  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130819 22:31:21  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
130819 22:31:21  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
```

Could anyone tell me, what could be wrong here?

Comment: All doesn't seem to be well with your filesystem.

Comment: This question is more about server/database administration than about programming and may be off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh... that's ugly.

Here's a fix. When uninstalling, copy the list of packages to be removed, then use that list to reinstall them afterwards.

http://www.blog.webcare.pk/2012/05/ubuntu-mysql-cannot-start-after-upgrade.html